# sql table results with prefix on result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm pulling in two tables in the same query but I want one of the tables to display it's rows with a custom prefix in front of it.

Example query:

```
SELECT pm.*, p.* 
FROM wp_postmeta pm, wp_posts p 
WHERE p.post_type = 'custom_post_type' AND pr.post_id = p.ID
```

This works currently but I'd like to distinguish the results from the pm table by adding "pm_" before the values. eg.

- `[meta_id] => 3041` would ideally become `[pm_meta_id] => 3041`
- etc etc

Comment: If your tables have columns with the same name, you **have** to use column aliases to disambiguate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pull in the columns individually, you can do:

```
SELECT
    pm.column1 AS pm_column1,
    pm.column2 AS pm_column2,
    ....
    p.*
FROM
    ...
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be a more global way to do this ie `pm.* = pm_*` but this will have to work for now.

Comment: But @Jackson, you shouldn't be selecting `*` in the first place, of course.  When you `SELECT` more columns than you need (often related to some sort of allergy to typing), you unnecessarily limit the number of possible query plans that the query optimizer can select from, in order to fulfill the request, and you may be ruling out a plan that could have performed better... among other reasons.

Comment: I used the asterisk mostly as an example but sometimes I do use the asterisk when I actually need all of the 3 columns in a bridge table. Are you saying it is better for performance to just type them all in instead of using the asterisk? +1 for the calling out allergies to typing